# How to restrict MSI installer to run only one instance even on multiple clicks?

Tags: installshield, windows-installer

I have made one MSI installer using InstallShield. But when I'm clicking multiple times on setup.exe, it creates multiple instances on that installer. But I want to restrict multiple instances of an installer even I click setup.exe multiple time. I want to show the message like "Another instance is already running".

Also I want to add this checks at EXE level and not at the MSI level. Because if I add it at MSI level then this check gets executed after extraction of MSI from EXE. I want to apply this check at EXE level and before extraction of MSI from EXE. So Is there any way to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

If the check is not already baked in, it will be hard for you to add it without writing your own bootstrap exe. If you can use an Advanced UI project or a Suite/Advanced UI project, I believe that bootstrap performs the check you request.

(But really, how many people who should be installing software launch an executable several times at once?)

Comment: I want to add solution for if user click on executable several times by mistake.